# When offline, how do you play YABOT single player maps with custom hotkeys?

Tags: starcraft-2

Alright, I want to practice some new builds with the popular YABOT (Yet Another Build Order Tester). I have downloaded the single player maps and dropped them onto my SC2 shortcut to start them. Now there's the problem that I don't log on to Battle.net but the map starts right away, this causes my customized hotkeys to not be loaded and applied.

How can I fix this?

*Basically, I want to start downloaded single player maps from my hard disk and use my normal hotkeys.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because your hotkeys are stored in the Battle.Net server, which you are not connecting to when loading a map directly from it's file. There is however a workaround, quoting:

> For those of you wondering if
>   you can run custom maps while online, yes you can, and here's how.
>
> 1. Close Starcraft 2
> 2. Open the map in the map editor
> 3. Start the map with File->Test Document
> 4. Wait until it loads up and quit the map
> 5. At that point, do not close your Starcraft 2, and log into your account
> 6. Alt-tab back at the map editor and do Test Document again
> 7. Bam, you'll play the custom map while connected to BNET, and you'll be able to watch replays

This way I'm able to access my hotkeys as I am connected to Battle.Net.

Edit: On newer versions there seems to be a much better approach:

> Go to: SC2 Folder \ Accounts \ Account Folder \ Hotkeys
>
> Copy the Custom.SC2Hotkeys to: SC2 Folder \ Hotkeys

Comment: the destination folder `SC2Folder\Hotkeys` hat to be created manually, it works now :) ty